# Изменение значения объекта по prototype и напрямую

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
function Human () {}
Human.prototype.val = 5;
Human.prototype.change = function () {
   Human.prototype.val = 10;
};

var man = new Human();
var woman = new Human();

man.val++;
woman.change(); //или man.change() - результат одинаковый
woman.val--;
Human.prototype.change(); 

console.log(man.val, woman.val); // 6, 9
```

Как работает этот код? Почему дальнейшие вызовы `man.change()`/`woman.change()`/... не меняют `val`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В коде в вопросе можно увидеть работу с прототипами и объектами, более нагляден может быть следующий код:

```js
function Human() {}
Human.prototype.val = 5;

var man = new Human();

console.log(man.hasOwnProperty('val'));
man.val++;
console.log(man.hasOwnProperty('val'));
```

Как видно из вывода: перед выполнением `++` свойства `val` непосредственно в объекте `man` отсутствует, и после выполнения - присутствует.

#### Почему так происходит?

При попытке получения значения свойства, если такого свойства нет = будет проверяться одноименное свойство в прототипе объекта, пока не будет найдено, либо пока прототипы не кончатся.

В случае присвоения (изменения) значения свойства, если оно отсутствует в объекте - оно (в большинстве случаев) будет в него добавлено.

Так как `.val++` сначала получает значение, оно берется из прототипа.

Далее оно увеличивается и сохраняется непосредственно в объекте. Поэтому последующие изменения значения в прототипе, не оказывают влияния на вывод `.val` так как, свойство начинает браться непосредственно из объекта, и до проверки прототипа дело не доходит.

Comment: Не успел я с ответом. В принципе, можно ведь сказать, что `man.val++`  - это в данной ситуации `man.val = man.__proto__.val + 1`? Вроде так нагляднее объяснение получается

Comment: Я понял. Значение сохраняется в объект. Я про это забыл. Спасибо, пошел перечитаю книгу  "JS шаблоны" . Или посоветуйте другие  книги кто знает? ( "Js сильные стороны " я читал )